# how to update value of Searchview and textView of MainAcitivity from java class

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am using `Searchview`. When I write query then a list shows and when i click the list item then I want to show the text or value of the clicked item in searchview. How can i do this. Search view and textview are both in *MainAcitivity.java*. I want to update the value of both earchview and  textview from CustomAdapter.java class.I want to show the value in SearchView when `onclick()` method of `convertView.setOnClickListener` is called.

**Here is code**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context c;
ArrayList<Planet> planets;
LayoutInflater inflater;
TextView nameTxt;

public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Planet> planets) {
    this.c = c;
    this.planets = planets;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return planets.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return planets.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    Log.d("getItemId is",":"+position);
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(inflater==null)
    {
        inflater= (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.model,parent,false);
    }

   nameTxt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    final int pos=position;
    nameTxt.setText(planets.get(pos).getName());
    nameTxt.getText().toString();

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(c,planets.get(pos).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            planets.clear();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}

}
```

I want to show the value when `onclick()` method of convertview is called.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom interface like

```
public interface PlanetItemListener{
    void onPlanetClicked(Planet planet);
}
```

Then require an instance of PlanetItemListener as a constructor parameter.

```
public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Planet> planets, PlanetItemListener listener) {
    this.c = c;
    this.planets = planets;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And in the click block notify the listener

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener. onPlanetClicked(planets.get(pos));
        }
    });
```

In make your activity implement PlanetItemListener, and in block do your logic `onPlanetClicked(Planet planet) {
  //your logic to do
}`

Answer (score 0):

First, get the `SearchView` or the `EditText` you want to update inside your adapter

```
    Context c;
    ArrayList<Planet> planets;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    TextView nameTxt;

    //add this line
    SearchView searchView;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Planet> planets, SearchView searchView) {
        this.c = c;
        this.planets = planets;
        this.searchView = searchView;
    }
```

This asks for a new parameter in your adapter, make sure you add it when setting the adapter to the `RecyclerView`.

Now we can update it the way we want

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        searchView.setText(planets.get(position).getName());
    }

});
```